# ffmpeg stream video file to fake webcam

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, webcam, v4l2

I'm trying to set up ffmpeg to forward video stream from file to dummy video device created by `v4l2loopback`

My command looks like following:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 -s 640*360 /dev/video0
```

However if I try to check it from browser, e.g. using http://testwebcam.com/ I only see some green silhouette. Probably I use wrong output format, but if I try  `-c:v mjpeg` it reports an error:

```
V4L2 output device supports only a single raw video stream
```

Any help appreciated.